# Learning Relational Normalization could someone clear this up for me?

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I have been reading up on this topic for certain piece of work but still this notation doesn't make sense to me

```
Relation R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) with the following functional dependencies:
Fd1: A → BCD
Fd2: AD → E
Fd3: EFG → H
Fd4: F → GH
```

Could someone briefly explain what this mean or let me know if there is a guide to this somewhere ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What notation are you having an issue with?

Comment: I dont understand what the part in in "code" means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)` refers to a relation and its constituent fields (A-H).

A functional dependency (notated `A -> B`) means that for a single value of A there is one and only one value of B.

In a case like this: `A -> BCD` it means that for a single value of A there is one and only one *tuple* of values BCD. A tuple is just a combination of fields.

So, let's look at some example data to see what is and is not a functional dependency:

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E
=========================
1  |  a  |  2  |  b  |  3
-------------------------
2  |  a  |  3  |  c  |  4
-------------------------
3  |  a  |  4  |  d  |  5
```

From the very rudimentary table above, we can deduce the following:

1. `A --> B` IS a functional dependency because for each value of A there is one and only one value of B.
2. On the other hand, `B --> A` is NOT a functional dependency because there are multiple possible values of A (1,2,3) for a single value of B ("a").
3. The same two conclusions above apply to all other columns with respect to column B, as well as tuples consisting of columns A,C,D, and E.

Hopefully that helps. If you update your question with more specifics I can address other problems in understanding that you may be having.

Comment: I do have certain questions to answer but I want to figure them out my self. Thanks anyway this helps a lot.